# iterating and mutating a Vec<String> from multiple tasks in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I have a `Vec<String>` called `v`.

**my goal is to concurrently iterate over my `vec`, process each element and remove it from the `vec` if the process was successful.**

*(my reason for deleting the element is to prevent other tasks to re-process an element again)*

I'm creating multiple `tokio::tasks` and iterating over them:

```rust
let list = Arc::new(Mutex::new(v));
let mut tasks = vec![];
for i in 0..10 {
    let list = Arc::clone(&list);
    let t = tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let mut locked_list = list.lock().await;

        for (index, item) in locked_list.iter().enumerate() {
            println!("processing {}", item);
            locked_list.remove(index); // cannot compile

            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(300)).await;
            println!("{} was removed from task {}", item, i);
        }
    });
    tasks.push(t);
}
futures::future::join_all(tasks).await;
```

this code does not compile due to this error:

> cannot borrow `locked_list` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

because its already borrowed in the for loop: `locked_list.iter().enumerate()`.

my First solution was wrapping the `locked_list` inside a `RwLock`, but I faced a dead-lock there, the first task will lock the list and it will stuck at
`locked_list.write().await.remove(index)` (which is when I used `RwLock`):

```rust
let t = tokio::task::spawn(async move {
    let locked_list = RwLock::new(list.lock().await);

    for (index, item) in locked_list.read().await.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("processing {}", item);
        locked_list.write().await.remove(index);
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(300)).await;
        println!("{} was removed from task {}", item, i);
    }
});
```

How can I solve this issue?
I've read multiple questions from stackoverflow but non of them seems to dealing with mutating and multi-tasking like this case..

Comment: Sounds like you want some sort of multi-producer, multi-consumer message passing channel, such as the one provided by [the async-channel crate](https://docs.rs/async-channel/1.8.0/async_channel/)? Alternatively, you might want to split your `Vec` into independent segments *before* you spawn your tasks.

Comment: @You I've thought about these two solutions before, the problem with them is that a task might fail to process one element, in that case, other tasks doesn't know about it and the failed element will not be processed by other tasks, while in the `removing element` approach, the item will be removed only when the process was successful, so it will automatically be picked by other tasks if it fails

Comment: can't your task retry if a element fail ?!

Comment: @Stargateur perhaps, but its much harder to implement a retry policy in a multi-threaded application

Comment: As written only one task ever works, because first thing you do is `lock` the list and you don't release the lock until the very end of the task. I think the right approach here is something with a mpmc channel like You suggested. On failure you can add the task back into the channel.

Comment: Instead of trying to remove the elements from the vector, I would suggest that you mark individual elements as processed and lock individual elements, i.e. have a `Vec<Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>>>` and each task can lock an element, check if it is already `None` and otherwise process it and set to `None`.

Comment: Can you just return your values to queue on failures?

Comment: You have to be really careful here with the suggested alternatives that you gain any speed improvements at all from multithreading and that the locking overhead doesn't exceed any advantage.

Comment: Are you aware how invasive a `remove` call in a `Vec` is? It potentially moves **all the elements** that come after the given element, which, in your case, means all of them. That's also why you won't ever be able to implement this with a `Vec` - you won't ever be able to process a single item without locking and therefore blocking all the other threads. This is just not a usecase that a `Vec` works for.